# Is Black Clover Mahou Tei no Ken canon?

Tags: black-clover

If I read correctly, Black Clover Mahou Tei no Ken was produced by Netflix, while the anime series was produced by japanese company Pierrot. Does this mean it's a sort of adaptation loosely based on the manga, or is it canon and part of the Black Clover manga/anime continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Black Clover Mahou Tei no Ken* isn't canon, but an OVA, since its events weren't adapted from manga.